# Is it safe to store tokens to JS Local Storage?

Tags: javascript, html, security, local-storage, token

I am making a file hosting. 
I need to know if it's safe to store tokens after user authentication to Local Storage.

Comment: Which tokens? What does it need to be safe against?

Comment: Auth tokens to identificate user when doing file operations

Comment: You could use HTTP-only cookies instead.

Answer (score 3):

Depends what kind of token really.

If they're oAuth2 bearer tokens, it's safe to store them: After all, the server will later know whether that token is too old and will ask you to renew it.

If it's an oAuth2 refresh token on the other hand, it should never even reach the client.

Other kinds of token? It will depend on their characteristics.

Answer (score -2):

There are two problems when using the *localStorage* :

- It can be cleaned at any moment by a tool (e.g. CCleaner) or when user manually clean the browser's data ;
- Anyone (applications...) can read it. And any app can write it too.

So, depending of what you store, it would be a security issue...

But why do you want to use localStorage instead of standard cookies ?

Comment: To be more concrete, I want to use sessionStorage to store token for a limited amount of time. Also, token becomes invalid after an hour or two.

Comment: That's the same thing that localStorage : any app can read and write the sessionStorage. The safest way is to use a PHP or Node.js session stored on the server (using $_SESSION in PHP for example)

Comment: Standard cookies have exactly the same two problems.

Comment: No, I'm talking about making a server-side session. You store an ID on the cookie, which is sent to the server, which associate it to a session that can' be accessed by the client. When you use session_start() on PHP to use the $_SESSION object, all this work is done automatically.

Comment: Persons who vote this post as not useful, can you explain why please ?